# cannot deal with dependencies in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I have 2 project (A and B) A is the sdk and the other is an application that uses sdk.

I want to join A to B with gradle and i don't know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to show a new MainActivity instance you need to declare an intent-filter in your project B manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
     <action  android:name="your.package.here.MainActivity" />
     <category    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"     />
```